# Does this proof work? Show $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=3x^2-4$ is NOT injective and NOT surjective.

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I had a different proof than the proof in the solution manual. My question is whether the proof is still valid, and if not, how I can improve. Here's what I came up with:

**Proof:** Show $f$ is not injective.

Observe that $f(-1)=3(-1)^2-4=3-4=-1$ and $f(1)=3(1)^2-4=3-4=-1$

$\implies f(-1)=f(1)$

However, $-1\neq 1$.

$\therefore f$ is not injective.

Show $f$ is not surjective.

Since we are dealing with squares, $f(x)=3x^2-4$ reaches its minimum value of $-4$ when $x=0$, meaning the codomain of $f$ is $[-4,\infty)$. This interval is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but it is not equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

$\implies$ the domain of $f$ does not map to every element of $\mathbb{R}$.

$\therefore f$ is not surjective. $\qquad\blacksquare$

Comment: Terminology about functions may vary but I think you meant "range" instead of "codomain". The codomain is $\mathbb R$, the range is $[-4,\infty)$ and surjectivity would mean that the range is all the codomain.

Comment: @Taladris ah, I see! I think I lumped those two together in my mind.

Comment: @Taladris other than that, was my proof ok?

Comment: Seems alright to me. When you are showing $f$ is not injective, you could alternatively use the fact that $f(x)$ is an even function and we have $f(-x) = f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @MathLover Ah, that makes sense! That's similar to what the course author did in the solution manual. She assumed $f(a)=f(b)$ and showed $a=\pm b$.

Comment: @blakedylanmusic: yes, perfect.